# how to change status checked on checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox

So i have this object

```
interface IFilterContent {
  id: number
  title: string
  status?: boolean
}

export interface IFilterDropdownOptions {
  id: number
  title: string
  content: IFilterContent[]
  functionOnChange?: (content: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
  isDate: boolean
}

const filterProps: IFilterDropdownOptions[] = [
{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Status',
    content: [
      { id: 1, title: 'Draft', status: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'In Review', status: false },
      { id: 3, title: 'Need Revision', status: false },
      { id: 4, title: 'Sent', status: false },
    ],
    functionOnChange: (data) => {
      if (data.target.checked === true) {
        console.log('Status ' + data.target.id + ' checked')
      } else {
        console.log('Status ' + data.target.id + ' unchecked')
      }
    },
    isDate: false,
  },
]
```

and this pages to load the object

```
<div className='content-checkbox'>
                      {opt.content.map((c) => (
                        <label className='label-container' key={c.id}>
                          <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            onChange={opt.functionOnChange}
                            id={c.title}
                            checked={c.status}
                          />
                          <span>{c.title}</span>
                        </label>
                      ))}
                    </div>
```

I want to change the status everytime the checkbox is checked into true. But I don't understand how.

My code is already printing the console.log everytime the checkbox is clicked. But the status won't change.

This is my expected outcome when I click the checkbox with id = 1

```
{ id: 1, title: 'Draft', status: true }
```

Also I already tried this
`filterProps.status = data.target.checked`

But it showing this `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'IFilterDropdownOptions[]'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the approach I took based on the project you shared with me.

I noticed you had a list of options you were passing as a prop to be rendered within a child component `<FilterDropDown/>`. Since you wanted the value of each checkbox to be controlled by the value of `option.content[index].status`, we need to do a few things.

First, we needed to let the parent component handle the state of the options.

`const [options, setOptions] = useState(filterProps);`

Next, we needed to create a method that handles how we would like to update the state whenever a checkbox is toggled.

```
const handleChange = (
    optionId: number,
    contentId: number,
    value: boolean
  ) => {
    setOptions((prev) =>
      prev.map((option) =>
        option.id !== optionId // Iterate over the array of options until we find the option we want to modify
          ? option // The id's did not match so we return the same object
          : // We found the option we want to modify, so we do a deep copy of all its data then modify it's content attribute
            {
              ...option,
              // Content is an array so we do the same thing that we did above
              content: option.content.map((item) =>
                item.id === contentId ? { ...item, status: value } : item
              ),
            }
      )
    );
  };
```

Both the options as well as the handle change method needed to be passed as props to the `<FilterDropdown options={options} handleChange={handleChange} />` component.

Lastly, you can destructure the props we passed.

```
const FilterDropdown: React.FC<IFilterDropdownProps> = ({
  className,
  options,
  handleChange,
})
```

Then update the input field by setting its `value` attribute and using the `onChange` handler we created.

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 value={c.status}
 onChange={(e) => handleChange(opt.id, c.id, e.target.checked)}
 id={c.title}
 checked={c.status}
 />
```

So in summary based on the code that was provided, whenever a check box is toggled:

1. We iterate through the provided list of options
2. Find the option that we want to modify by its id
3. Iterate through the list of `option.content`
4. Find the content item we want to modify by its id
5. Update the value of `option.content[index].status`

Since the parent component controls the state of the options and we are passing that data to the child component, data changes in the parent are reflected in the child.

**NOTE:** For your `handleReset` feature to work, you'll need to do something similar to what was discussed in this solution. Move that logic up to the parent component and modify the state of options accordingly.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-dust-412636?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Comment: this is my components are structured https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-sound-b97p4q?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx . Can you help me by write your sandbox based on my code? because I'm kinda confused.

Comment: I forked the project and left some comments. Hopefully this helps. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-dust-412636?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Did you use an AI like ChatGPT to generate (parts) of this answer?

Comment: No, I did not do that.